# Household receptacle - For a 2-wire, can I tap the adjacent bond for grounding?

Tags: electrical

I have a 2-wire circuit in my utility closet that I'd like to connect to a receptacle. In the closet is the bonded water & gas pipes. Can I tap into that bond to provide a ground to the receptacle?

Comment: Are the bonding *wires* accessible in said closet, or does it only provide access to the *pipes*?

Comment: yes, it's accessible in the closet, exposed

Answer (score 2):

They changed the rules in 2014 to greatly liberalize the rules for Retrofitting Grounds.

They did NOT include using water and gas pipes as a substitute for electrical wires.

However, they did allow pulling ground off the Grounding Electrode System, which does include bonds to a water pipe.  So you can bond to the wire, not the pipe.  A split-bolt connector is an easy way to tap a fat bare ground wire.

Comment: how about just soldering the ground to that fat wire?

Comment: @bbowens -- mechanical connectors (I'd use an ILSCO GTT-2-2 or equivalent) are far easier and quicker to install than having to do a wrapped (Western Union type) splice, then solder (as solder alone isn't sufficient to hold a joint together under extended fault current conditions)

Comment: @bbowens What is the conductivity of solder?  (betcha have always just presumed "enough").  Look it up :)

Comment: I don't know; I just figured that a soldered connection was better than a crimped connection, provided that there is adequate stress relief.

Comment: @bbowens -- a proper compression joint will cold-weld the wires inside to each other and the crushed connector barrel, producing a gas-tight and mechanically sound joint without any other steps needed.  Solder isn't robust enough under fault current (overcurrent/short circuit) conditions to hold the joint together (it melts as it isn't quite as conductive as copper and is much lower-melting for that matter), and then you're reliant on the mechanical integrity of the splicing method used to keep the wires from parting.

Comment: Oh, it's like 10 times less conductive. My brain melted when I saw the actual figure. It's no surprise wires do too. That's why a Western Union splice gets-er-done purely with surface contact, and the solder is just there to arrest abrasion and keep corrosion out.

Comment: thank you, everyone. this has been very informative!